# Reply to Trustpilot Review Service Reviews API returning 400 Bad Request

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, namedcredentials, httpresponse

This is my code in Salesforce

```
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('callout:TrustPilot/private/reviews/'+reviewId+'/reply?token='+token);
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
            reqString ='{'+
                        '"message": "'+replyBody+'",'+
                        '"authorBusinessUserId": "'+buserId+'"'+
                       '}';
            req.setBody(reqString);
            Http http = new Http();
            HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
```

This code returns a 400 Bad Request error. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong as the exact code line works in a test environment but not in my production.

Endpoint - callout:Trustpilot - this is basically 'https://api.trustpilot.com/v1'

Any help would be appreciated!!

I'm trying to post a reply to a Trustpilot review using REST API

The expected response would be StatusCode - 201 Created

Comment: This is possibly due to the payload you are sending to Trustpilot, have you inspected the `replyBody` data to ensure it is as you would expect?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think the same since I just tried to post the same reply the user was trying to post on prod from my sandbox and it is failing in sandbox as well. I have contacted Trustpilot to find out how the payload I send is validated on their end, so I can apply the same validation on my end.

Answer (score 0):

The payload I sent had line breaks which I needed to accomodate with escape characters which resolved the issue